# Ng-repeat functionality doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Today is my first day with Angular.js , and I stuck at a basic controller :

my APP.js

```
 (function()
    { var app = angular.module('store', [ ] );

        app.controller('StoreController', function() 
      {
          this.product =  gem;
      });

     var gem = [
          {name:'John', price:25, description:'boy',soldout: false,canpurchase:true},
          {name:'Kohn', price:25, description:'boy',soldout: false,canpurchase:true}
          ]
          //not mentioned:false


    })();
```

Index.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="store">
        <script src="js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        <title>Purple</title>
    </head>
    <body ng-controller = "StoreController as store">
        <script src="js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <h1>{{"Create your CV"}}</h1>
        <div ng-repeat="products in store.product">

        <div ng-hide="store.product.soldout">
        <h1> {{store.product.name}} </h1>
        <h2><em class="pull-right">{{store.product.price | currency}}</em></h2>
        <h3> {{store.product.description}} </h3>
        <button ng-show = "store.product.canpurchase"> Add to cart </button>
        </div>

        </div></body></html>
```

My code is working fine , but NG - repeat is not working, if I don't choose ng-repeat and display each item as an array then I am getting a display but not with "ng-repeat" .. Any idea's what am I missing ?

Please dont mark this as negative, I have done a lot of research before asking this question

Code on fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/68Dkz/2/

Comment: Inside the ng-repeat, I'm pretty sure you should be just using `products` instead of `store. product`, so try for example `products.name` instead of `store.product.name`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is working version using controller alias `store` as shown. Note that `product` was changed to `products` in controller since the array contains more than one product. I think you are gtting confused about which is array and which is the individual item within the `ng-repeat` due to this

```
<div ng-repeat="product in store.products">

    <div ng-hide="product.soldout">
      <h1> {{product.name}} </h1>
      <h2><em class="pull-right">{{store.product.price | currency}}</em></h2>
      <h3> {{product.description}} </h3>
      <button ng-show="product.canpurchase">Add to cart</button>
    </div>

  </div>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/o50Edv4BGIjT55wYMawQ?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: +1 the rest our answers address style issues primarily, only yours hits the original underlying issue

Comment: Thanks, it works, but please explain why it works now ? Second question, if you have changed product to products then how are you referring as product.name (and why is it still working )

Comment: @Mgetz actually the first time I've used controller alias. Once you learn without it is hard to add it into your methodology

Comment: @charlietfl I have yet to find a use for it, I'm more likely to smurf name my module than mess up the controller name and need to alias it.

Comment: @Abhinav it works because it follows the proper syntax outlined in angular docs

Comment: @Mgetz main advantage I think is it is easy to see which scope something is derived from when nesting controllers

Comment: @charlietfl that might be worth a KB self answered post if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: @Mgetz my problem converting would be I would be looking for an object in scope called `store` since that's what I am used to

Answer (score 0):

`store` is your module not your scope you don't [need it in the iteration](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02), do `products in product` instead

```
<div ng-repeat="products in product">
   <div ng-hide="products.soldout">
      <h1> {{products.name}} </h1>
      <h2><em class="pull-right">{{products.price | currency}}</em></h2>
      <h3> {{products.description}} </h3>
      <button ng-show = "products.canpurchase"> Add to cart </button>
   </div>
</div>
```

- stop aliasing your controller, it is unnecessary and may cause issues with the html compiler
- using `products` as your iterator is confusing, I would suggest making the collection `products` and the iterator `product`

Comment: not quite correct, `store` is the controller and needs to be used in the markup when defining `ng-controller` using `as`

Comment: @charlietfl `storeController` is the controller, and only needs to be referenced in the initial `ng-controller` directive, aliasing the controller is not wise as it's walking over the module.

Comment: look at `ng-controller = "StoreController as store"`

Comment: It does;nt help.... changing from products in store.product to products in product..

Comment: Error is somewhere here : var gem = [
          {name:'John', price:25, description:'boy',soldout: false,canpurchase:true},
          {name:'Kohn', price:25, description:'boy',soldout: false,canpurchase:true}
          ] ... because when i remove the array and create a single product, then everything is fine..

Comment: @Abhinav stop aliasing your controller, you don't need to

Comment: @Abhinav using plural on `products` here is misleading `products` will be individual object in array `product`